# Disable Mission Control in Big Sur

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, bug, mission-control

I would like to completely disable Mission Control in Big Sur. If there is a way to stop it from triggering when I drag a window to the top of a screen that would also be greatly appreciated. I've disabled all options in System Preferences aside from `Displays have separate spaces`, which I would like to keep for other reasons.

It appears that `defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool TRUE && killall Dock` used to work, but no longer does. Please tell me there is some way to disable this annoying behavior. Thanks.

*From comments:*
This issue can apparently only be triggered if

1. There are multiple displays &
2. Displays have separarate Spaces is enabled.

Comment: What *precisely* triggers when you drag a window to the top of the screen? Nothing at all happens here. Tested on a Mac Pro still on Mojave & a new iMac M1 running Big Sur.

Comment: I need to slide the window up against the top of the screen fairly quickly for this to trigger, so it's a somewhat inconsistent. But when it happens, suddenly every single window from every screen shifts into view. It extremely distracting when I'm quickly moving a bunch of windows around.

Comment: I suspect you are actually accidentally using the trackpad gesture for Mission Control - by default a 4-finger swipe up. You should be able to disable or change that in Trackpad prefs. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895

Comment: Thanks but I've already disabled that gesture and experience this problem with both the trackpad and an external mouse.

Comment: I cannot repro your result. Banging a window into the top of the screen does not in itself trigger Mission Control.

Comment: That's a really highly annoying problem with Big Sur! A somewhat related post: https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle/issues/250#issuecomment-710784481 The only advice there was to reduce the speed of your dragging and/or not go too high :(

Comment: @Tetsujin I can reproduce this every time (mouse and trackpad), if I go up quickly.  Might be related to having Better Touch Tool installed, but I can't find any setting that would enable or disable this.

Comment: @Gilby No, it is not connected to Better Touch Tool, it also happens without it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you have separate spaces enables for the different displays? That's a requirement to reproduce this. The behaviour should be unrelated to the hardware as long as you have multiple displays.

Comment: @Tetsujin We *do* know that the OP has multiple displays, otherwise they would not need the option `Displays have separate spaces`.

Comment: @sam - D'oh, missed that. I have to withdraw from the discussion as I cannot test those criteria. This detail needs adding to the question, though. If a very specific setup is required to repro, then only people with that setup can test.

Comment: My testing on a MacBook without a second display: It is triggered by "Displays have separate Spaces" enabled.  This turns the behaviour on and off.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I came across so far is to use hammerspoon:

```lua
disableTopScreenEdgeForDragging = hs.eventtap.new({ hs.eventtap.event.types.leftMouseDragged }, function(e)

    local loc = e:location()

    if loc.y == 0.0 then
        hs.mouse.setAbsolutePosition({ x = loc.x, y = 0.01 },
                1337 -- a hack, do not remove
        )
    end
end)

disableTopScreenEdgeForDragging:start()
```

https://gist.github.com/raxigan/588bb3c97ec2a2a3b3042846fbf7fe51